# Overflow auto with height 100%

Tags: css

I have a problem with this code in my CSS, because it run only with a short dimension:

```
div.active {
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

With this code I obtain the scroll-bar on my `DIV`. I would have a `DIV` that fits the page and I try to use this code:

```
div.active {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

But with this code the scroll-bar disappears.
How can I do to obtain the scroll bar with a `DIV` that fits the page?

Comment: Why do you have to have a scrollbar, if there is not enough content to warrant it?

Comment: @mori57: The OP didn't say that there has to *always* be scroll bars, only that the scroll bar feature doesn't work with `height:100%`. Which is correct because the `div` will just resize and extend past the viewport

Comment: @musefan: True, but it's still a valid question as to why there is the concern over a lack of a potentially unneeded UI element. Sometimes the proper answer is ensuring that the OP is asking the right question to begin with.

Comment: @mori57: What I am saying is that the OP isn't concerning over a lack of an unneeded UI element. I imagine they don't really care if it's dispalyed there or not when the content is smaller than the container, but the problem is that the content **is** larger and the scroll isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your attempt is that to use a percentage height then the element needs to belong to a parent with a fixed height. There are a couple of ways to fix a height, but as you need it to fill the screen then I would recommend the following HTML:

```
<div class="fixed">
    <div class="active">
    </div>
</div>
```

With this additional CSS:

```
div.fixed{
    position:absolute;
    top:2px;
    bottom:2px;
    left:2px;
    right:2px;
}
```

Note that I used `2px` to make it more obvious that it works in the demos below, use whatever you need)

Then you can use your original CSS:

```
div.active{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/kajQ5/), and [one with content](http://jsfiddle.net/kajQ5/1/)

Comment: OP does not provide any proof that his content /is/ large enough to require scrolling, nor do we know that his content is in document flow (not using position:absolute, or uncontained floats), so even if he uses the method you've described, if his content is not long enough to prompt the `.active` container to require scrollbars, then overflow: auto is not going to fix his problem, as in this fork of your solution with content: http://jsfiddle.net/B2zgy/1/

Comment: @mori57: One of us is really misunderstanding his question, and based on the fact the OP makes **zero** mention of having to force a scroll bar to **always** be there then I think it is you. My understanding is the OP wants the scroll bar to show when the content is larger than the page. My solution does this, and I have also highlighted why the [other upvoted answer does not](http://jsfiddle.net/XHKnp/). Yes we don't know about the document flow scenario, but it is clear that the `height:100%` is the part that does not work...

Comment: ...my solution addresses that with the only reason I can think of that would cause it not to work (i.e. not having a fixed height parent)

Comment: @JoachimLow: Relative will not work because it isn't able to know the height of the window. using absolute with top, left, bottom, right means it can be sized to match the window, and will resize when then window resizes. Is my example the correct result you are looking for? Is so, then what is your concern with using absolute positioning?

Comment: @musefan: I have a rectangular area and in this area i would see my text. But with position:absolute, the text exit from my rectangle. If i use position:relative i have the text in my area but the scroll bar doesn't work.

Comment: "How can I do to **obtain the scroll bar with a DIV that fits the page**?" <- That sounds like forcing a scroll bar to me. 
I think the OP needs to clear this up with a more complete example of what he's trying to do. A jsFiddle from the OP would work wonders to clear the confusion, or at least a chunk of representative markup so we can see how he's trying to nest what in relation to each other.

Comment: @JoachimLow: If you have additional parent element then you need to apply the absolute position on the the first one, and any sub-parent can use `height:100%`, [for example](http://jsfiddle.net/kajQ5/2/)

Comment: @mori57: Yes, a more complete example would be concise. And the phrase you quoted as it should be reworded: `"I can obtain the scroll bar with a fixed height DIV, but I cannot obtain it with a DIV that fits the page"`... the key part is the explicit CSS that shows the difference between it working correct with `height:200px` and not working with `height:100%`. Why would the OP say the first part works it the problem was with `overflow: auto;`? If that was the issue then the first CSS would also be wrong. The only thing that changes from working to non-working is the height, simple deduction.

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct behavior. If you want to always have the scroll bars, change it to `overflow: scroll;`

Comment: No, it will enforce the scroll bars, if the content is less, than it's fine to use `auto`

Comment: @Mr.Alien your comment is the preferred usage, but technically Joachim asked how to have scroll bars on a div that fits the page, which means `overflow: auto;` wouldn't have scroll bars showing.

Comment: @TylerH yes they won't but it's `height: 100%;` may be he will need `height: 100%` for the parent elements as well...

Comment: -1: [It doesn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/XHKnp/). I am making an assumptions about the OP's HTML but I think it is a fair one given the CSS included in the question